# Android Progressbar not rotating and appears with arrow in Oreo

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: ProgressBar image in both Pie device and Oreo device.]

Am facing the issue of ProgressBar appears with an Arrow and not getting rotate as expected only in Pie devices. It appears without Arrow and rotates well in Oreo and other devices. Kindly provide any valuable suggestions.

The Legend **who marked the question as Duplicate**, would also kindly requested to check the answer for the posted and suggested questions respectively.

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Did you try in real device or in emulator?

Comment: i tried with Samsung A20 device

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think is not a problem of code but of developer options of your device or emulator. You have probably disabled animation scales. 
Go to seetings > developer options > drawing section > and enable the three animation scales:

1. window animation scale
2. transition animation scale
3. animator duration scale.

You can put for exemple animation scale 1x.

Comment: You'r right, after enabling the options. it is working. Thanks